# Splitiing a string array into multiple subarrays in java based on prefix

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have several string inputs(registration number of students) from the user and I have to store them into different arrays based on their year of studying and print the output.
For example, if string begins with "18" i have to store it as a 4th year student. If it begins with "19" i have to store it as 3rd year student and so on.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class reg {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter no of students");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    String[] arr = new String[n];
    System.out.println("Enter registration numbers");
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i]=scan.nextLine();

    }

    String[] arr1 = new String[n];
    String[] arr2 = new String[n];
    String[] arr3 = new String[n];
    String[] arr4 = new String[n];
    String[] arr5 = new String[n];


    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        if(arr[i].startsWith("18")){
            for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
                arr1[j] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        else if(arr[i].startsWith("19")){
            for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
                arr2[j] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        else if(arr[i].startsWith("20")){
            for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
                arr3[j] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        else if(arr[i].startsWith("21")){
            for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
                arr4[j] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        else{
            for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
                arr5[j] = arr[i];
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("4th year students are");
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println(arr1[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("3rd year students are");
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println(arr2[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("2nd year students are");
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println(arr3[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("1st year students are");
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println(arr4[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

    }
    
}
```

The output I'm getting is just the last input matching my condition getting printed n times (no. of students input).

How can I solve this issue?

Edit :

Input and expected ouput :

No of students :

7

Enter registration numbers :

20ABC123

19ABC111

18ABC000

18ABC001

21ABX144

20ABX000

19ABC099

Expected Output:
4th year students are

18ABC000

18ABC001

3rd year students are

19ABC111

19ABC099

2nd year students are

20ABC123

20ABX000

1st year students are

21ABX144

Comment: do you have some example input data and expected result to test against? What debugging have you done?

Comment: What do you think `for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){ arr1[j] = arr[i]; }` does?

Comment: for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){ arr1[j] = arr[i]; } I added the 2nd for loop to make sure that indexing is proper for the subarray as "i" keeps increasing after every iteration so I cant just write it as arr1[i]=arr[i];

Comment: @Pshemo The code is not readable at-least for me, expected output part is not clear. Is this the way to ask a question?

Comment: @Vikas Acharya I edited the question

Comment: @kpalod but did you notice what do you do in each iteration of that loop? You are assigning to *each* index of `arr1` element `arr[i]`. In other words you are filling it entirely with current value of `arr[i]`. You don't want that. Instead you want to assign `arr[i]` to *one* position, probably first non-null one (you can store its index in variable like `amountOfElementsInArr1` or `year1StudentCounter`).

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce new 5 variable for keeping track of total student in each category so that you can put next student on next empty position in category.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter no of students");
int n = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
String[] arr = new String[n];
System.out.println("Enter registration numbers");
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    arr[i]=scan.nextLine();

}

String[] arr1 = new String[n];
String[] arr2 = new String[n];
String[] arr3 = new String[n];
String[] arr4 = new String[n];
String[] arr5 = new String[n];
int studntFirstYear = 0;
int studntSecondYear = 0;
int studntThirdYear = 0;
int studntForthYear = 0;
int studntElse = 0;


for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    if(arr[i].startsWith("18")){
        arr1[studntForthYear] = arr[i];
        studntForthYear++;
    }
    else if(arr[i].startsWith("19")){
        arr2[studntThirdYear] = arr[i];
        studntThirdYear++;
    }
    else if(arr[i].startsWith("20")){
        arr3[studntSecondYear] = arr[i];
        studntSecondYear++;
    }
    else if(arr[i].startsWith("21")){
        arr4[studntFirstYear] = arr[i];
        studntFirstYear++;
    }
    else{
        arr5[studntElse] = arr[i];
        studntElse++;
        
    }

}
System.out.println("4th year students are");
for(int i = 0;i<studntForthYear;i++){
    System.out.println(arr1[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("3rd year students are");
for(int i = 0;i<studntThirdYear;i++){
    System.out.println(arr2[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("2nd year students are");
for(int i = 0;i<studntSecondYear;i++){
    System.out.println(arr3[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("1st year students are");
for(int i = 0;i<studntFirstYear;i++){
    System.out.println(arr4[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
```